# webkit mask in javascript function on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I'm trying to do this inside `loadingisCompleted`

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($('body').hasClass('home')) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#tol-header').css('-webkit-mask-image','-webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(1.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.00, rgba(19, 40, 39, 1)))');

        } else {
            $('#tol-header').css('background','transparent');
        };
    };
});
```

Purpose:

1. Default background: transparent
2. On scroll to be executed: -webkit-mask-image .....
3. No influence on the elements which are situated in the header.

My less file contains

```
#tol-header { background: transparent; }
```

The final result is that I have permanent "transparent" opacity on/over all elements (menus, logo, etc) in the header, no matter if I scroll or not, nothing in common with what I would like to get.

If I change the places of scrollTop - background: transparent; else - -webkit-mask .... It works perfect, as I background (without any influences on other elements; as I want), but ... it works even when I'm not scrolling and I'm at the top of the page.

Would be thankful if somebody can help.

Comment: Can you share your HTML structure please?

Comment: <body id="top" <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="tol-header" >
        <header id="theader">
            <div class="navigation" id="navigation">
                <div class="cf">
                    <div class="row"> .......

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a stab at what you're wanting to do here as your question lacks a few key details.

I believe you want `$('#tol-header').css('-webkit-mask-image', 'none')` in the else as well so the webkit mask is removed again.

Comment: Thank you. I can post more, whatever is needed. Added it at the { else } but its partitialy works - it's removed the mask when I'm not scrolling. When scrolling only opacity is applying on the elements in the header (menus, logo nav links), while actually it doesn't apply any background.

Comment: you need to change `-webkit-mask-image` to `background` .

Comment: So inside `if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0)` it should be `$('#tol-header').css('background', '-webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, color-stop(1.00, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.00, rgba(19, 40, 39, 1)))')`